# Слово факт в начале предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Факт, без Саши стало скучнее.
>   Факт, что без Саши стало скучнее.

Какой синтаксической конструкцией является слово **факт**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом предложении — вводное предложение; употреблено в модальном значении "уверенность".

Во втором — главная часть сложноподчинённого предложения.

Чуть подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-035.htm) с аналогичными примерами:

> **Примечание**. Сопоставление вводных слов, сочетаний слов и предложений свидетельствует об отсутствии резких границ между ними. Это сопоставление лишний раз подтверждает наличие переходных явлений в синтаксисе. Особенно показательны в этом плане омонимичные синтаксические конструкции, различающиеся лишь функционально. Ср.: ***Известно***, что он хороший парень (известно — главная часть сложноподчиненного предложения). — ***Известно***, он хороший парень (известно — вводное предложение). — *Он, **известно**, хороший парень* (известно — вводное слово).